# Servicenow adding multiple choice into a workflow

Tags: workflow, servicenow, itil

I am developing a workflow and at one point the workflow can go into 3 directions. Let's call them A, B and C. But unfortunately I don't have the info in SNOW so, a person needs to choose the direction of the flow.
What would be the best way to integrate some kind of mc question into a workflow? 
It's the first time for me to create a complex workflow, so I have no Idea. I thought about adding an event where the user has to select something. But is this the right approach ?

Any help is upvoted, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Configure this in Additional Properties while creating a Workflow.

You can change the sub-flows based on these conditions defined.

[Read more here](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Creating_a_Workflow#Configuring_Additional_Properties&gsc.tab=0)